# Ошибка Pyinstaller Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, установка, pyinstaller

Пишу приложение на Python Tkinter.
В приложении ошибок нет

Вот код:

```py
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip
import os
import webbrowser

def windowInfo():
    def url2():
        webbrowser.open('https://vk.cc/9SFvMF')
    def url3():
        webbrowser.open('https://vk.com/kipelov_aria')
    def url4():
        webbrowser.open('https://vk.me/kipelov_aria')

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Дополнительная информация')
    window.geometry('500x500')
    window.config(bg='skyblue')
    window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

    textInfo = Label(window, text='''Название: GB-bite and file
    Версия: V1.0-BETA
    Разработчик(и):
    - Матвей Воронцов (FULL-STACK)
    Язык программирования: Python 3.7.2
    Доп.Модули языка: Tkinter, Pyperclip, OS, webbrowser

    Инструкция по использованию:''', fg='black', bg='skyblue')
    textInfo.config(font=('Times', 15))
    textInfo.pack()

    butUrl2 = Button(window, text='Инструкция/документация')
    butUrl2.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=url2)
    butUrl2.pack()

    textAll = Label(window, text='Прочее...', fg='black', bg='skyblue')
    textAll.config(font=('Times', 15))
    textAll.pack()

    butUrl3 = Button(window, text='Страница разработчика')
    butUrl3.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=url3)
    butUrl3.pack()

    butUrl4 = Button(window, text='Задать вопрос')
    butUrl4.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=url4)
    butUrl4.pack()

    window.mainloop()

def url():
    webbrowser.open('https://vk.cc/9SFvMF')


def entryInfo():
    entInfo = os.path.getsize(ent.get())

    if entInfo <= 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер в байтах: ' + str(entInfo))
    elif entInfo > 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер в байтах больше ' + str(entInfo))

    text3.config(text='Размер в битах: ' + str(entInfo / 0.13))
    text4.config(text='Размер в КБ: ' + str(entInfo / 1024))
    text5.config(text='Размер в КБит: ' + str(entInfo / 128))
    text6.config(text='Размер в Мбит: ' + str(entInfo / 131072))
    text7.config(text='Размер в Мб: ' + str(entInfo / 1048576))
    text8.config(text='Размер в Гбит: ' + str(entInfo / 134217728))
    text9.config(text='Размер в ГБ: ' + str(entInfo / 1073741824))


def entryInfo_dir():
    entInfo = ent.get()

    totalSize = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(entInfo):
        totalSize = totalSize + os.path.getsize(os.path.join(entInfo, filename))

    if totalSize <= 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер всех фалов в байтах: ' + str(totalSize))
    elif totalSize > 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер всех фалов в байтах больше ' + str(totalSize))

    text3.config(text='Размер в битах: ' + str(totalSize / 0.13))
    text4.config(text='Размер в КБ: ' + str(totalSize / 1024))
    text5.config(text='Размер в КБит: ' + str(totalSize / 128))
    text6.config(text='Размер в Мбит: ' + str(totalSize / 131072))
    text7.config(text='Размер в Мб: ' + str(totalSize / 1048576))
    text8.config(text='Размер в Гбит: ' + str(totalSize / 134217728))
    text9.config(text='Размер в ГБ: ' + str(totalSize / 1073741824))

def entryInfo_save():
    entInfo = os.path.getsize(pyperclip.paste())

    if entInfo <= 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер в байтах: ' + str(entInfo))
    elif entInfo > 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер в байтах больше ' + str(entInfo))

    text3.config(text='Размер в битах: ' + str(entInfo / 0.13))
    text4.config(text='Размер в КБ: ' + str(entInfo / 1024))
    text5.config(text='Размер в КБит: ' + str(entInfo / 128))
    text6.config(text='Размер в Мбит: ' + str(entInfo / 131072))
    text7.config(text='Размер в Мб: ' + str(entInfo / 1048576))
    text8.config(text='Размер в Гбит: ' + str(entInfo / 134217728))
    text9.config(text='Размер в ГБ: ' + str(entInfo / 1073741824))


def entryInfo_dir_save():
    entInfo = pyperclip.paste()

    totalSize = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(entInfo):
        totalSize = totalSize + os.path.getsize(os.path.join(entInfo, filename))

    if totalSize <= 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер всех фалов в байтах: ' + str(totalSize))
    elif totalSize > 1073741824:
        text2.config(text='Размер всех фалов в байтах больше ' + str(totalSize))

    text3.config(text='Размер в битах: ' + str(totalSize / 0.13))
    text4.config(text='Размер в КБ: ' + str(totalSize / 1024))
    text5.config(text='Размер в КБит: ' + str(totalSize / 128))
    text6.config(text='Размер в Мбит: ' + str(totalSize / 131072))
    text7.config(text='Размер в Мб: ' + str(totalSize / 1048576))
    text8.config(text='Размер в Гбит: ' + str(totalSize / 134217728))
    text9.config(text='Размер в ГБ: ' + str(totalSize / 1073741824))


root = Tk()
root.title('GB-bite and file')
root.geometry('660x550')
root.config(bg='skyblue')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

title = Label(root, text='GB-bite and file', fg='red', bg='skyblue')
title.config(font=('Obelix pro', 39))
title.pack()

text = Label(root, text='Введите путь к файлу/папке:', fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text.config(font=('Times', 18))
text.pack()

ent = Entry(root)
ent.config(width=60)
ent.pack()

but = Button(root, text="Подсчитать размер одного файла")
but.config(width=33, height=2, fg='black', bg='goldenrod', command=entryInfo)

but2 = Button(root, text='Подсчитать размер всех файлов в папке')
but2.config(width=33, height=2, fg='black', bg='salmon', command=entryInfo_dir)

but.place(x=90, y=225)
but2.place(x=333,y=225)

textTwo = Label(root, text='Пример: C:\Program Files (x86)\Weather help\weather_help.exe', fg='grey', bg='skyblue')
textTwo.config(font=('Lucida Console', 10))
textTwo.pack()

butPaste = Button(root, text='Вставить скопированный путь к файлу')
butPaste.config(width=37, height=2, fg='black', bg='white', command=entryInfo_save)
butPaste.pack()

butPaste = Button(root, text='Вставить скопированный путь к папке')
butPaste.config(width=37, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=entryInfo_dir_save)
butPaste.pack()

text2 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text2.config(font=('Times', 15))
text2.place(x=90, y=270)

text3 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text3.config(font=('Times', 15))
text3.place(x=90, y=300)

text4 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text4.config(font=('Times', 15))
text4.place(x=90, y=330)

text5 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text5.config(font=('Times', 15))
text5.place(x=90, y=360)

text6 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text6.config(font=('Times', 15))
text6.place(x=90, y=390)

text7 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text7.config(font=('Times', 15))
text7.place(x=90, y=420)

text8 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text8.config(font=('Times', 15))
text8.place(x=90, y=450)

text9 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='skyblue')
text9.config(font=('Times', 15))
text9.place(x=90, y=480)

butInfo = Button(root, text='Доп.Информация')
butInfo.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=windowInfo)
butInfo.place(x=0, y=510)

butUrl = Button(root, text='Инструкция/документация')
butUrl.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='silver', command=url)
butUrl.place(x=185, y=510)

root.mainloop()
```

ошибка Pyinstaller:

```
C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\main>pyinstaller -F -w -i "Desktop\main\icon.ico" GB-bite_and_file.py
158 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
158 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
159 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
161 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\main\GB-bite_and_file.spec
166 INFO: UPX is not available.
170 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Матвей\\Desktop\\main', 'C:\\Users\\Матвей\\Desktop\\main']
171 INFO: checking Analysis
171 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
171 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
176 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
181 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
8361 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
8367 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
10865 INFO: Caching module hooks...
10883 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\main\GB-bite_and_file.py
11417 INFO: Loading module hooks...
11418 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
11597 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
11598 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
11776 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
11777 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\main\GB-bite_and_file.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 502, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 793, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py", line 11, in <module>
    hiddenimports, binaries, datas = add_qt5_dependencies(__file__)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 536, in add_qt5_dependencies
    more_binaries = qt_plugins_binaries(plugin, namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 147, in qt_plugins_binaries
    pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\матвей\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 132, in qt_plugins_dir
    """.format(namespace, ", ".join(paths)))
Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: C:/users/ìàòâåé/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins


C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\main>
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Paths checked: C:/users/ìàòâåé/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins посмотрите как Pyinstaller видит ваше имя)

Comment: Учите питон? тогда для начала избавьтесь от кирилицы в пути

Comment: Попробуйте сделать экзещник через pysimplegui-exemaker". У меня такая же была ошибка.